# How to retrieve image from database to datagridview in c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am using SQLSERVER 2008 R2 database as my backend in my C# windows application.
I stored images as built-in datatype **image** in database instead of storing it in **blob** or **byte**.
So now I want to retrieve that image in my DataGridView from that Database,but it is giving error like **Parameter is not valid**.

Can anyone help me out ??

Thanks in Advance.